# Timer Function is not working in android?

Tags: android, timer, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to bet the latitude and longitude using BroadcastReceiver for three minutes an  once. But my timer is not working by adding the result function.without result(),its working. I don't know...Anybody kindly rectify my error.

Comment: Hey It will be called on every half an hour.

Comment: am using this function in BroadcastReceiver,may be this is Called Frequently.i dunno whats the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the Timer interval `30 minutes = 1800000 milliseconds` and you are using `180000 milliseconds` which is `3 minutes`.

Seems you are having some problem. You can check this which works for every 5 seconds,

```
        Timer mTimer = new Timer();
        TimerTask mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Timer", "every 5 seconds");
            }
        };
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimerTask, 5000, 5000);
```

Comment: ya sorry 3 minutes.But it Called Frequently.

Comment: without Calling result(),its working fine.But in my result function just i called the webservices.whats my problem

Comment: seems you are mistaken some where you are starting the timer again.